# Image quality degrades with FBSDKshareDialog and FBSDKsharephoto

Tags: ios, facebook, image, swift

I have used the following code to capture a screenshot before using the image to post to Facebook:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(frame.size.width,frame.size.height), false, 0)
self.view?.drawViewHierarchyInRect(CGRectMake(-frame.origin.x, -frame.origin.y, view.bounds.size.width, view.bounds.size.height), afterScreenUpdates: false)
let screenShot  = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
return screenShot
```

In the first instance I used the `Social Framework` and `SLComposeViewController` adding the screenshot with `addImage`. The image on the dialog box and ultimate post were perfect but this method does not allow you to choose your friends.

I then decided to use use `FBSDKDialog` as follows:

```
let photo : FBSDKSharePhoto = FBSDKSharePhoto()
photo.image = screenShot
photo.userGenerated = false
photo.caption = contentDescription

let photoContent : FBSDKSharePhotoContent = FBSDKSharePhotoContent()
photoContent.photos = [photo]
photoContent.contentURL = NSURL(string: self.contentURL)

let shareDialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
shareDialog.fromViewController = self
shareDialog.shareContent = photoContent
shareDialog.delegate = self

if !shareDialog.canShow() {   
    shareDialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogMode.Native
} else {   
    shareDialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogMode.FeedBrowser
}
shareDialog.show()
```

The code works perfectly but the image quality on the share dialog box is extremely poor. Yet when I do make the post the image quality on the timeline is perfect.

I have tried to compress the image but nothing seems to make any difference.
Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything wrong. This is probably a way Facebook optimizes sharing.